# Using convolution to get the distribution of the difference of two hypoexponential variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, convolution, exponential-distribution

I am trying to find the distribution function of a random variable $Z = X-Y$ with $X$ following a  $\text{Hypo}(\mu_1,...,\mu_n)$ and $Y$ following a $\text{Hypo}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m)$. Then $X$ and $Y$ both have the support region $[0,\infty]$. Additionally, I assumed that all parameters are distinct such that we can use the PDFs:

\begin{equation}
 f_X(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}l_{k}(0)\mu_ke^{-\mu_kx}, \; f_Y(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{m}l_{k}(0)\lambda_ke^{-\lambda_ky}
\end{equation}

with $l_1(x),...,l_n(x)$ are the *Lagrange basis polynomials*.

I tried to use the convolution theorem for probability theorem, such that:

\begin{equation}
 f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f_{X}(z+y)f_Y(y)\text{d}y
\end{equation}

but I end up obtaining something of the form:

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k_1 = 1}^{n}\sum_{k_2=1}^{m}\frac{l_{k_1}(0)l_{k_2}(0)}{\mu_{k_1} + \lambda_{k_2}} \mu_{k_1} \lambda_{k_2} e^{-\mu_{k_1}z}
\end{equation}

which is a divergent when you take the integral over the support region of Z, which I believe is $[-\infty, \infty]$.

Is there somebody more familiar with this topic and willing to help me?

Comment: I would suggest to use the moment generating function instead of convolution. But i doubt there is an explicit result.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a particular reason convolutions don't work in these situations as it seems really intuitive?

Comment: Convolution is usually tricky. I do not know which is better here. It's just an intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you computed the convolution in the wrong way, since you didn't account for z positive or negative. I would do it like this:

$f_Z(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_X (x) f_Y(x-z) dx $

When $z <0$ the integral is evaluated in $(0,\infty)$, while for $z \ge 0$ in $(z,\infty)$. In the end I get the following density for $Z$:

$$ f_Z(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{s=1}^{m} \frac{l_s(0)l_k(0)\lambda_s\mu_k}{\lambda_s+\mu_k} (\mathbb{I}_{\{ z <0 \}} + e^{-(\lambda_s+\mu_k)z}\mathbb{I}_{\{ z \ge 0 \}})$$

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. I think you made a slight typo as I ended up with \begin{equation} f_Z(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{s=1}^{m} \frac{l_s(0)l_k(0) \lambda_s \mu_k}{\lambda_s + \mu_k} \left( e^{\lambda_s z} \text{I}_{\{z < 0 \}} + e^{-\mu_{k}z} \text{I}_{\{z \geq 0\}} \right). \end{equation} However, when I take the integral over the support region of the variable $z$ I indeed get approximately 1.

Comment: @KristanvanRenssen you are totally right! I forgot to multiply by a factor $e^{\lambda_s z}$.